# How to properly use a set key of a dictionary in Python3?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, key-value

I would like to use a dictionary = `{string pair: int}`, where the key is a string pair.

My question is how to properly set the keys so that the dictionary knows that `('a', 'b') == ('b', 'a')`?

eg. I don't want this:  `dict = {('a', 'b'):10, ('b', 'a'):12}`

but want this  `dict = {('a', 'b'):22}`

Answer (score 2):

I would use `frozenset`s as the keys (they don't depend on order):

```py
>>> d = dict()
>>> d[frozenset(("a", "b"))] = 42
>>> print(d[frozenset(("b", "a"))])
42
```

Edit: Another option would be to always sort the keys before using them:

```py
>>> d = dict()
>>> d[tuple(sorted(("a", "b")))] = 43
>>> d[tuple(sorted(("b", "a")))]
43
```

Note that using `frozenset(...)` will ignore duplicated keys: `frozenset(("a", "a", "a")) == frozenset(("a",))`, while `tuple(sorted(...))` will consider those things different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaultdict from collections and add the values.

```
from collections import defaultdict

li = defaultdict(list)
li[("a", "b")].append(10)
li[("a", "b")].append(12) 
for key, value in li.items():
    print(key, sum(value))

Output: ("a", "b") 22
```